# Empty <ObjectApiName>.object-meta.xml after sfdx cli pull command

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I have a custom object. In the new scratch org I changed a custom button URL of the object using Salesforce UI. Then I run `sfdx force:source:pull` and retrieved 2 changed files: the changed weblink and the object's xml. Weblink file is fine but the object xml file is broken as it's content vanished.

My `<ObjectApiName>.object-meta.xml` before the pull:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>Accept</actionName>
        <type>Default</type>
    </actionOverrides>
    ...
    ...
    <sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>
    <visibility>Public</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

after:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableEnhancedLookup>true</enableEnhancedLookup>
</CustomObject>
```

Why it happened and how to make it preserve the object's xml?

Comment: This could be a issue with the `source:pull` command if you can replicate it consistently. For instance, there's some open issues about using source:pull after creating new objects and pulling the dependent metadata changes on [profiles](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/311) and [layouts](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/337). I'd have to test on my end if the same occurs for your given scenario

Comment: I know this is a year old but I also had this issue.  I found a solution was to make some change in the UI to something like the search layout for the object, then when I pulled all the data came back into the object.  It seems that some changes to the object cause the metadata to vanish and some will bring it back

Answer (score 1):

As far with the tests I made the org just pulls the changes you did or the metadatas you explicity put in the package.

If you want to get everything whithin the Object you should get all CustomFields, all Actions, etc. and the Object you want, for example.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>MyCustomObject__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Hello @Luis, is it a package.xml file? How can I use it with the force:source:pull command?

Comment: @MikhailIvanov I use the following command sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest C:\FolderName\myManifest.xml